# Python : Subprocess wait is not working in Apache

Tags: python-3.x, apache, subprocess, mod-wsgi

I am using Python 3.7.4,Apache 2.4, When I am running the below code

```
  p1 = subprocess.Popen('python filename.py abc def', shell = True)
  p1.wait()
```

Its working fine locally, But when deployed in Apache, Its not waiting for the process to complete and its it is executing next lines. How to execute Subprocess in Apache and wait for the result. And below is the configuration in **httpd.conf** file

```
WSGIScriptAlias  /appname E:/abc/xyz.wsgi 
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
<Directory E:/abc>
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: did you try with `p1.communicate() `

Comment: No... This is also not working